# osgi NoClassDefFoundError - Directory of jars

Tags: java, osgi, classpath

I have a directory with tons of jar files. To be more concrete: Apache Spark. Now I want to write a Java/osgi program using the Spark library. What is the best way of doing that?

One way would be to bundle the entire 200MB into a osgi bundle. Result would be a huge plugin with the same jar files that are on the server anyhow and in worst case incompatible with the server's Spark version.

Another option is to add all 200MB of jar files into the project's lib folder and treat them as embedded libraries. Same issues as above.

The only other option is to hack the class loader at runtime, adding Spark's jar directory to the class path. That's not nice either.

But frankly, this use case is outside of what osgi should do, in my opinion. osgi is used to control dependencies including versions and I ask to use the version that is installed already. A contradiction, isn't it?

Do you have a suggestion? Something I did overlook?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

OSGi is about software engineering. About verifying that your compile time dependencies match up to compatible runtime dependencies. When you follow the (simple) rules, you end up with a much more reliable system than without OSGi because nothing is 'assumed', as in so many non OSGi projects.

Unfortunately, this means you need to get the metadata right. Although huge amounts of code now have OSGi metadata people have a natural tendency to take short cuts. At that moment you have the worst of both worlds. You do not get the many benefits but you still pay the price. OSGi is imho very much an 'all the way' technology, there are few benefits by picking some parts.

If I was faced with your problem I'd analyze what my code needed from Spark and see if I could turn that into a number of clean, cohesive, and uncoupled service APIs. I would write my code against these APIs. In the OSGi runtime I would use my own dependencies. My Spark service implementations I would register from outside the framework so that the Spark class space and the OSGi class spaces are separate. However, this is not trivial since so many APIs tend to leak implementation details and implementation dependencies.

Trying to port an open source project that was not designed for OSGi with 200 Mb dependencies is a major task in my experience. It is very similar to try to add security to a program not designed from scratch to take security into account.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to call spark from OSGi quite a while ago and gave up on it. Spark is a mess regarding dependencies and even when you sort the dependencies out it is still the question if spark or one of its dependencies does class loading tricks. So I do not think it is worth the effort to try to get spark run in OSGi.

Maybe you can create a microservice that offers an api tailored to your needs on top of spark as a rest service. So spark runs outside the OSGi process.

Comment: Yes, that would be one option. But since it is about performance, an additional hop is not nice either.
Agree on Spark and dependencies, so that's no option either.

I wonder if my problem is even higher. At the moment I try to get all being executed in debug mode and fail even with that. 

I have added in the manifest.mf file the lines

Bundle-ClassPath: META-INF/,    .

and made the spark jars visible by a symbolic link from META-INF/spark.

Tried using the Bundle-ClassPath: ., external: /home/spark/jars/


Nothing works. Always the NoClassDefFound exception.

Comment: Okay, one answer seems to be "do not add directories but individual jar files". Gee, that's hundreds also and might change in the next Spark version.